# Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (Eclipse based IDE) has big problems with deadlocks

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using GGTS to create some projects in Grails but this IDE is terribly slow.

I have two projects in my IDE (sometimes both running) and after small changes GGTS starts to build workspace which takes A LOT of time, sometimes it never ends and just crashes, sometimes it makes so hard deadlock that I MUST restart my computer.

My environment: win 7 64-bit, Intel i5-2500 3,30GHz, 8GB RAM, GGTS v. 3.1.0, java 1.6.0_30, grails 2.2.0.

I've read that there is possible to do something like this:
Window - > Preferences - > General -> Workspace - > Linked Resource - Disable linked resource,
but I'm not sure if I can do this, cause Grails projects are connected with this place, I believe: C:\Users\username.grails\2.2.0\projects

What can I do? Is the only way out this problem is buying IntelliJ or working with some text editor and console? How to repair this buggy Eclipse?

Comment: Have you updated your Eclipse .ini file to use a reasonable amount of memory? I wouldn't use anything under 2G since you can afford it.

Comment: Hmmm... Trustly saying, I've never heard about it before. Tell me how to do it, I think it may be possible solutions, cause my problem in 99% is not enough memory problem (even if I have a lot of free RAM, I've monitored that)

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: I have a similar issue on Windows - at this point I have been restarting eclipse whenever I see a slowdown (6-8 hours), it seems to resolve the issue

Comment: The following links say that this could be an eclipse 4.2 issue. Try GGTS based on Eclipse 3.8
================================================================================
[STS Jira 3058](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3058)
================================================================================
[Eclipse bug 385272](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272) There is apparently some patch available.
================================================================================
btw, I haven't myself ran into issues with GGTS 3.1.0 on mac.

Comment: @user1811107 Yeah, but slowdown in my case shows up suddenly, and sometimes GGTS does not response and I just don't want to kill the task 'cause i don't wan't to lose my work.

Comment: @user1811107 Thanks for this link, I'll check it if Eclipse.ini won't help.

Comment: @Dave Newton it didn't help. I have set: --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M 
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
It still crashes.

Comment: @Dave Newton Looks like it works. First building workspace didn't crash ggts. Thank you very much. Pity that you didn't write it as an answer, I would give you some reputation for it :)
BTW, isn't it strange that ggts needs 2g of memory to work properly?

Comment: Nah, I find that particularly with dynamic languages, IDEs need a *lot* of "leg room" so I just assume a 2g minimum.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Project->uncheck the "Build Automatically" option. This is by default checked. So, when ever you do any change in the code, it automatically tries to build every time. Unchecking this option will save you a lot of time, as you can run it whenever you want (it builds only when you run the code.)

Answer (score 2):

I use emacs for Grails development, but I would definitely recommend IntelliJ, unless you can work without code assist.

From what I've seen Eclipse with plugins, STS or GGTS are extremely buggy when working with Grails:

- Workspace corruptions
- Poor completion for dynamic methods
- Sometimes you can't save files
- etc.

Comment: It's true it's buggy, but it has never interrupted my work until now. Actuall problem is critical, I just can't work.

Comment: It's 2015 and I can't second/third/fourth this enough! I don't know how much better IntelliJ is yet, but I've lost so many hours trying to make it work on GGTS. Honestly the name "Grails" being right there in the title had me thinking it must be robust

Answer (score 1):

Putting this: -vm
C:\devsw\java\jdk7_67\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll in my GGTS.ini (and restarting GGTS) has stopped the blue circle from spinning.